# Can't read from file issue in Swagger UI

Tags: swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I have incorporated `swagger-ui` in my application.

When I try and see the `swagger-ui` I get the documentation of the API nicely but after some time it shows some error icon at the button.

The Error message is like below:

> [{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file
> http://MYIP/swagger/docs/v1"}]

I am not sure what is causing it. If I refresh it works and shows error after few seconds.

Answer (score 111, accepted):

I am guessing "http://MYIP/swagger/docs/v1" is not publicly accessible.

By default swagger ui uses an online validator: online.swagger.io. If it cannot access your swagger url then you will see that error message.

Possible solutions:

1. Disable validation:

   `config.EnableSwagger().EnableSwaggerUi(c => c.DisableValidator());`
2. Make your site publicly accessible
3. Host the validator locally:

You can get the validator from: https://github.com/swagger-api/validator-badge#running-locally

You will also need to tell swaggerui the location of the validator

`config.EnableSwagger().EnableSwaggerUi(c => c.SetValidatorUrl(<validator_url>));`

Comment: Can you please tell in which file we could configure the validator to be disabled?

Comment: That depends on which framework you are using. For example with Web Api 2 in Startup.cs:

`public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
           ...
           
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
        }`
           
Then the validator could be configured in SwaggerConfig.cs

Comment: For the next person - when I downloaded and got the validator-badge running locally, I found out that my swagger json was valid.  The error was because my swagger.json isn't available remotely (which is what I [and probably you] want).

Comment: Config file is available in .\App_Start\SwaggerConfig.cs

Comment: Any chance to fix this if I use the publicly available docker image of swagger ui?

Comment: Is there any security risk or other kind of risk for disabling validation?

Answer (score 20):

To supplement the accepted answer...I just uncommented one line in the SwaggerConfig.cs.  I only wanted to get rid of the red error on the main swagger page by disabling the validator.

```
// By default, swagger-ui will validate specs against swagger.io's online validator and display the result
// in a badge at the bottom of the page. Use these options to set a different validator URL or to disable the
// feature entirely.
//c.SetValidatorUrl("http://localhost/validator");
c.DisableValidator();
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing !

Comment: Where can I find swagger config ?

Comment: I use the Swashbuckle NuGet package for Swagger, and SwaggerConfig.cs gets put under the App_Start folder.

Comment: Config file is available in .\App_Start\SwaggerConfig.cs

Answer (score 14):

If you are using files from [`swagger-ui`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/) github repo, then you can disable schema validation from your `index.html` file by setting `validatorUrl` to `null` in it:

```
window.onload = function() {

  // Build a system
  const ui = SwaggerUIBundle({
    url: "/docs/open_api.json",
    dom_id: '#swagger-ui',

    validatorUrl : null,   # <----- Add this line

    deepLinking: true,
    presets: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.presets.apis,
      SwaggerUIStandalonePreset
    ],
    plugins: [
      SwaggerUIBundle.plugins.DownloadUrl
    ],
    layout: "StandaloneLayout"
  })
```

Comment: This is exactly the solution i needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

If you using [PHP Laravel framework](http://laravel.com) with [L5-Swagger](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/L5-Swagger) just uncomment

```
'validatorUrl' => null,
```

from the config file `/config/l5-swagger.php`

Answer (score 1):

Setting `this.model.validatorUrl = null;` in `dist/swagger-ui.js` worked for me ..

```
// Default validator
if(window.location.protocol === 'https:') {
  //this.model.validatorUrl = 'https://online.swagger.io/validator';
  this.model.validatorUrl = null;
} else {
  //this.model.validatorUrl = 'http://online.swagger.io/validator';
  this.model.validatorUrl = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**To anynoe having similar issue when using Swashbuckle.OData:**

I was having issues to integrated Swagger with our OData endpoints (using *ODataController* for API and *Swashbuckle.OData* NuGet package). I had to write our own document filter for it and add it:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger(c =>
                {
                    c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "OurSolution.API");
                    c.DocumentFilter<SwaggerDocumentFilter>();
                    //c.CustomProvider((defaultProvider) => new ODataSwaggerProvider(defaultProvider, c, GlobalConfiguration.Configuration));
                    c.IncludeXmlComments(GetXmlCommentsPath());
                    c.UseFullTypeNameInSchemaIds();
                    c.RootUrl(req => ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AppUrl"]);
                })
            .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
                c.DisableValidator();
            });
```

Apparently in order to avoid validation error I had to comment out line which is setting *ODataSwaggerProvider* along with turning off validator as mentioned in posts above. This makes usefulness of Swashbuckle.OData questionable yet I didn't test whatever it works with vanilla Swashbuckle.

Note: I used approach described on GitHub page for Swashbuckle.OData but it was not working: showing no possible endpoints at all. Maybe somebody knows better solution.