# Can't read from file issue in Swagger UI Docker image

Tags: docker, swagger-ui

Based on question [Can't read from file issue in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188386/cant-read-from-file-issue-in-swagger-ui)

So what i need is disable validatorUrl but for docker image (swaggerapi/swagger-ui:v3.34.0) using environment variable. Is that possible?

I've tried to put swagger-config.yaml with content: validatorUrl: none into /usr/share/nginx/html inside docker image - it didn't help

Comment: you need more explanation