# swagger corrupt after deployment

Tags: c#, swagger

I've written some endpoints in webApi C#. On my dev machine, when I run my code and open swagger all endpoint are available as expected. When I deploy my code to another server when I run swagger I only see a couple of my post methods. I'm missing some post methods and all my get methods.

From the deployed server in swagger I receive an error: -

> {"schemaValidationMessages":[{"level":"error","message":"Can't read from file http://192.168.19.3/WooService/swagger/docs/v1"}]}

I have tried re-deploying several times, removing the service from IIS and recreating, but none of these seem to work. Can someone tell me where I'm likely to find this file on my local service and where I should place it on the server I'm deploying too, or if anyone knows another way to resolve this issue.

My Swagger config is very basic

```
using System.Web.Http;
using WebActivatorEx;
using WooService;
using Swashbuckle.Application;

[assembly: PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(SwaggerConfig), "Register")]

namespace WooService
{
    public class SwaggerConfig
    {
        public static void Register()
        {
            var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;

            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
                .EnableSwagger(c =>
                    {
                        c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "WooService");
                    })
                .EnableSwaggerUi();
        }
    }
}
```

As mentioned nothing has really changed other than a couple of endpoints. The config must be ok because it runs fine locally. Its on the deployed machine it's suddenly not showing all end points

Comment: What happens if you open the url in your browser? Can you access the file?

Comment: Post your startup.cs

Comment: It looks like you have given wrong path for swagger.json in SwaggerEndpoint method

Comment: If I open the url, I see 4 of my post methods and nothing else. I've deployed several times. Originally, all my methods where showing. It seems that the v1 file is corrupt, but I dont know where it is. My startup.cs shoulld be fine as nothing has changed there, and as I said it works fine on my dev box it's only failing after deploy

Comment: If you use automated deployments through a CI, check, if the right branch is deployed. Maybe you deploy an older version of your app with lesser endpoints defined.

Comment: Can you give more details? .net version? Swashbuckle version, etc, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't read from file issue in Swagger UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32188386/cant-read-from-file-issue-in-swagger-ui)